# C# console application not running stand-alone after being published

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm rather new to C# and Visual Studio.

The problem  I have is after I publish my C# console app in Visual Studio. The console app is not handling the augments correctly and is throwing an error.

I have setup a few [Launch Profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hXEU.png) to test out how the console app will behave with different arguments. They all pass and give me the expected results when I run the Debug and Release Profiles.

However, when I go to publish and I select self-contained and select Produce single file. [(Published Profile Settings.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzOvm.png) The app no longer works as expected.

I get the following error:

```
Generic Exception Handler: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'paths')
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String[] )
   at AMP_New_Project.AMP_New_Project_Folder.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\eriskedahl\Documents\GitHub\JMS\NewAMP_Proj_Console\AMP_New_Proj.cs:line 135
PS C:\Users\erisk\Documents\GitHub\JMS\NewAMP_Proj_Console\Releases>
```

Now the error itself is fine and looks like my the exception handling is working, but I have a debug profile to check this and the path is allowed to be null. There is an if statement to handle what happens when a path argument is not supplied.

```
if (strWorkPath == null || strWorkPath.Length == 0)
{
    strWorkPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)!;
}
```

It seems the console app is not self-contained and is missing some references but not sure where else to check. Why would the app behave differently after being published?

When I run debug, and no path is given, the the variable strWorkPath is null and then gets set to the console app's current working directory.

As mentioned this works completely fine and as expected when I run the app through the debug in Visual Studio, I only get this error when I run the published version. If I open a Powershell or cmd window and go to the Bin/Release folder and run the application from there I also get the expected results. The App fails once I copy the exe file to a different folder.

Comment: look at your `System.IO.Path.Combine` call...

Comment: This is the Path.Combine call. When I do a step through the line is doing what I would expect it to do. 
string[] paths = { strWorkPath, sb.ToString() };

string fullpath = Path.Combine(paths);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When publishing as a single file, the build system bundles all of the assemblies which make up your application together.

The [`Assembly.Location` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=net-7.0) say:

> In .NET 5 and later versions, for bundled assemblies, the value returned is an empty string.

So we're passing an empty string to [`Path.GetDirectoryName`, which says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?view=net-7.0#system-io-path-getdirectoryname(system-string)):

> Directory information for `path`, or `null` if path denotes a root directory or is null.

So that's probably what's happening: `Assembly.Location` returns an empty string, because the assembly has been bundled together with a load of other assemblies as part of the publish, and `Path.GetDirectoryName` turns that into `null`.

To get the application's location in a way which supports bundling, use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Note that this is **not** the current working directory. The CWD is the directory that the user is in when they run your application. It's normally assumed that if the user passes a relative path to your application (e.g. as a command-line argument), the application should interpret that as relative to the user's CWD.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not that you are using self-contained deployment but that you also using single-file deployment (one of the checkboxes).

Docs for single-file deployment and executable mention that [some `Assembly` APIs will not work in single-file deployment mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli#api-incompatibility), including the `Location`, which will return an empty string:

| API | Note |
| --- | --- |
| `Assembly.CodeBase` | Throws `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`. |
| `Assembly.EscapedCodeBase` | Throws `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`. |
| `Assembly.GetFile` | Throws `System.IO.IOException`. |
| `Assembly.GetFiles` | Throws `System.IO.IOException`. |
| `Assembly.Location` | Returns an empty string. |
| `AssemblyName.CodeBase` | Returns `null`. |
| `AssemblyName.EscapedCodeBase` | Returns `null`. |
| `Module.FullyQualifiedName` | Returns a string with the value of `<Unknown>` or throws an exception. |
| `Marshal.GetHINSTANCE` | Returns -1. |
| `Module.Name` | Returns a string with the value of `<Unknown>`. |

Which leads to `Path.GetDirectoryName` returning `null`.

There are some workarounds mentioned:

- To access files next to the executable, use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory`
- To find the file name of the executable, use the first element of `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`, or starting with .NET 6, use the file name from `System.Environment.ProcessPath`.
- To avoid shipping loose files entirely, consider using embedded resources.

So you can use `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory` to determine the directory.